# Is it possible to factor very large integers greater than 100 digits in the blink of an eye?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to factor very large integers greater than 100 digits in the blink of an eye ?
What I mean is that is there any fast algorithm in literature to do the job. I know of GNFS but they are slow as soon as we cross 100 digits. Also I want to do the job on my laptop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author seems to be using the question for self-promotion. More precisely, it seems like they are using MSE as a publishing platform, instead of going through peer review (note their answer to their own question).

Comment: If that was possible, the [RSA challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-2048) would be solved in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 2):

No, GNFS is the best algorithm that's known for this task. 
With just a laptop you cannot go very far. Buy a super computer....

RSA wouldn't be very secure if there'd be a fast algorithm.....